Summing the derivatives of multiple series from InfluxDB 1.8 with InfluxQL?
Our monitoring solution is based on Telegraf + InfluxDB + Grafana, and we're having trouble visualizing the I/O statistics of our ZFS pool.
Our data is collected with the inputs.zfs plugin of Telegraf, which reads /proc/spl/kstat/zfs/pool0/objset-*. The content for objset-* is something like this:
56 1 0x01 24 6784 23432440338 2539326268410625
name                            type data
dataset_name                    7    pool1/bt1
writes                          4    759249885
nwritten                        4    12439388631969
reads                           4    1928504366
nread                           4    7900302380313
nunlinks                        4    19586
nunlinked                       4    19586

Notably, reads, writes, nread, nwritten are cumulative data provided by the kernel, so we need non_negative_derivative("reads") to get the reads IOPS.
Each objset-* file maps to a single series, so we have this in our InfluxDB:
> SHOW SERIES FROM "zfs_pool";
zfs_pool,dataset=pool0,host=mirrors2,pool=pool0
zfs_pool,dataset=pool0/repo,host=mirrors2,pool=pool0
zfs_pool,dataset=pool0/repo/alpine,host=mirrors2,pool=pool0
zfs_pool,dataset=pool0/repo/archlinux,host=mirrors2,pool=pool0
zfs_pool,dataset=pool0/repo/debian,host=mirrors2,pool=pool0
zfs_pool,dataset=pool0/repo/fedora,host=mirrors2,pool=pool0
zfs_pool,dataset=pool0/repo/ubuntu,host=mirrors2,pool=pool0

The problem is, these objset-* contains statistics for that specific dataset, but none of its descendants. So in order to get the I/O stats for the entire pool, we have to apply non_negative_derivative on each of these series, and then sum it all up.
With Grafana, here's a straightforward query we have at hand:
SELECT
  sum("reads") AS "reads",
  sum("writes") AS "writes"
FROM (
  SELECT
    non_negative_derivative(mean("reads"), 1s) AS "reads",
    non_negative_derivative(mean("writes"), 1s) AS "writes"
  FROM "zfs_pool"
  WHERE ("host" = 'mirrors2' AND "pool" = 'pool0') AND $timeFilter
  GROUP BY time($interval), "host"::tag, "pool"::tag, "dataset"::tag fill(linear)
)
WHERE $timeFilter
GROUP BY time($interval), "pool"::tag fill(linear)

We have some 90 series (as shown by SHOW SERIES CARDINALITY FROM "zfs_pool"), and the above query times out after 30 seconds. With the time range set to "last 30 hours", Grafana calculates MD (max number of data points) = 1827 and interval = 1m (1 minute).
We tried moving the derivative to the outer query:
SELECT
  non_negative_derivative(sum("reads"), 1s) AS "reads",
  non_negative_derivative(sum("writes"), 1s) AS "writes"
FROM (
  SELECT
    mean("reads") AS "reads",
    mean("writes") AS "writes"
  FROM "zfs_pool"
  WHERE ("host" = 'mirrors2' AND "pool" = 'pool0') AND $timeFilter
  GROUP BY time($interval), "host"::tag, "pool"::tag, "dataset"::tag fill(linear)
)
WHERE $timeFilter
GROUP BY time($interval), "pool"::tag fill(linear)

... which unfortunately did not complete within 30 seconds either.
We tried prepending the query with EXPLAIN in the InfluxDB shell, which yields something we find no particular utility:
QUERY PLAN
----------
EXPRESSION: mean(writes::integer)
NUMBER OF SHARDS: 1
NUMBER OF SERIES: 86
CACHED VALUES: 0
NUMBER OF FILES: 86
NUMBER OF BLOCKS: 86
SIZE OF BLOCKS: 3211

EXPRESSION: mean(reads::integer)
NUMBER OF SHARDS: 1
NUMBER OF SERIES: 86
CACHED VALUES: 0
NUMBER OF FILES: 86
NUMBER OF BLOCKS: 86
SIZE OF BLOCKS: 7480

EXPRESSION: mean(writes::integer)
NUMBER OF SHARDS: 1
NUMBER OF SERIES: 86
CACHED VALUES: 0
NUMBER OF FILES: 86
NUMBER OF BLOCKS: 86
SIZE OF BLOCKS: 3211

EXPRESSION: mean(reads::integer)
NUMBER OF SHARDS: 1
NUMBER OF SERIES: 86
CACHED VALUES: 0
NUMBER OF FILES: 86
NUMBER OF BLOCKS: 86
SIZE OF BLOCKS: 7480

Our database contains a single retention policy that's mostly default settings:
> SHOW RETENTION POLICIES;
name    duration   shardGroupDuration replicaN default
----    --------   ------------------ -------- -------
autogen 12960h0m0s 168h0m0s           1        true

Can anyone advise how we should optimize this query so that it returns our desired information in a reasonable time?
